# Is it possible to run Java ME apps in Palm Z22?

Tags: java, mobile, palm-os

I want to develop a java app that should run in Palm Z22. Will it be possible?

If you could provide me some start point I would appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Z22 runs palmos 5 so it should run the [IBM j2me package.](http://mytreo.net/downloads/ibm-websphere-everyplace-java-virtual-machine,1313.html)